# Powershell - How to grab multiple XML attributes in a loop

Tags: xml, powershell, scripting

What is the most efficient way to output the users in the format below:

Vinny,Blue|Red

Mike,Blue

LeeRoy,Blue

Jenny,Blue|Red

Deborah,Red

Using the following code:

```
<Section1 name="colors" category="colors">
  <Section2 name="Blue" category="color">
    <Section3 name="Users" category="users">
     <Section4 name="Vinny" category="user"></Section4>
     <Section4 name="Mike" category="user"></Section4>
     <Section4 name="LeeRoy" category="user"></Section4>
     <Section4 name="Jenny" category="user"></Section4>
    </Section3>
  </Section2>
  <Section2 name="Red" category="color">
    <Section3 name="Users" category="users">
      <Section4 name="Vinny" category="user"></Section4>
      <Section4 name="Jenny" category="user"></Section4>
      <Section4 name="Deborah" category="user"></Section4>
    </Section3>
  </Section2>
</Section1>
```

With the condition that if the users (Section4) appear in multiple colors (Section 2), they are separated by the | character.

At first I dumped all the colors in one array, then was going to dump all the users in another array, then I got stuck trying to do a couple of things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to achieve this. 
That way, all your users and colors are linked together in one list.

In the example below, I am making use of the `Select-XML` statement to get the users, the `Select-object` to select multiple properties and finally I am using calculated properties to use change the property name returned and also get the color node.

```
[xml]$xml = @'
<Section1 name="colors" category="colors">
  <Section2 name="Blue" category="color">
    <Section3 name="Users" category="users">
     <Section4 name="Vinny" category="user"></Section4>
     <Section4 name="Mike" category="user"></Section4>
     <Section4 name="LeeRoy" category="user"></Section4>
     <Section4 name="Jenny" category="user"></Section4>
    </Section3>
  </Section2>
  <Section2 name="Red" category="color">
    <Section3 name="Users" category="users">
      <Section4 name="Vinny" category="user"></Section4>
      <Section4 name="Jenny" category="user"></Section4>
      <Section4 name="Deborah" category="user"></Section4>
    </Section3>
  </Section2>
</Section1>
'@


$value = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath '//Section4'

$UsersArray = $value | select @{'n'='user';'e'={$_.Node.name}},@{'n'='color';'e'={$_.Node.ParentNode.ParentNode.name}}

# You can now manipulate your results as you see fit
$UsersArray | Sort user | ft
```

**Useful references**

The  `@{'n'='';'e'=''}` shown in the example statement are shortcut for `@{'name'='';'expression'=''}`, which are [Calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx). In your case, it allow us to get easily the color value once we are at the User level without any additional statement.

[Select-XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-5.1) reference for examples on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

(very) ugly but gives the desired output

```
[xml]$xml = '<Section1 name="colors" category="colors">
    <Section2 name="Blue" category="color">
        <Section3 name="Users" category="users">
            <Section4 name="Vinny" category="user"></Section4>
            <Section4 name="Mike" category="user"></Section4>
            <Section4 name="LeeRoy" category="user"></Section4>
            <Section4 name="Jenny" category="user"></Section4>
        </Section3>
    </Section2>
    <Section2 name="Red" category="color">
        <Section3 name="Users" category="users">
            <Section4 name="Vinny" category="user"></Section4>
            <Section4 name="Jenny" category="user"></Section4>
            <Section4 name="Deborah" category="user"></Section4>
        </Section3>
    </Section2>
</Section1>'

$users = $xml.Section1.Section2.Section3.Section4.Name | Select-Object -Unique

foreach($user in $users) {
    $matchedColors = @()
    foreach($color in $xml.Section1.Section2.Name) {
        if($xml.Section1.Section2.Where({ $_.Name -eq $color }).Section3.Section4.Name -contains $user) {
            $matchedColors += $color
        }
    }
    "{0},{1}" -f $user, ($matchedColors -join "|")
}
```